# Salesforce LWC interact with SVG with script

Tags: html, svg, lwc

I am trying to display a SVG that contains a script inside a LWC and have some interaction with it.
This SVG is an exploded views of my product. My LWC will contains this SVG and a list of product. When the use goes over the exploded view, the corresponding product in the list will be highlighted.

[Exploded view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUjQU.png)

I am able to display the SVG, and to hightlight the elements with a script inside the SVG. However I can't interact with it. In the LWC I can't access the DOM elements inside the SVG, and if I dispatch an event inside the SVG script, I can't listen to it in the LWC.

For example the following code only works if I open Chrome dev console and click on the SVG DOM element. Before that the  document.getElementById('svgLogo') is null.
document.getElementById('svgLogo').addEventListener("mouseoversvg", function(){console.log('I listen')}, false);

Do you have any idea on how I fix this problem ?

LWC HTML:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={product}>
        <lightning-card>
            <div id="main-div" style="height:30%;width:100%;">
                <div id="svg-div" style="float:left;height:10%;width:50%;">
                    <object id="svgObject" data={svgURL} type="image/svg+xml"></object>
                </div>
....
```

My SVG script:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 141.8 245.5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 141.8 245.5;" xml:space="preserve" id="svgLogo">


<g id="g1">
    
        <image style="overflow:visible;enable-background:new    ;" width="321" height="554" id="frenchpress" xlink:href="frenchpress.png"  transform="matrix(0.4417 0 0 0.4417 0 0)">
    </image>
    
        <path id="Path" dataid="SBG" opacity="0" onfocus="highlightStrand(evt)" onblur="dehighlightStrand(evt)" onmouseover="highlightStrand(evt)" onmouseout="dehighlightStrand(evt)" class="st0" d="
        M99.3,147.9L99.3,147.9l5.5-8.5l-4.4-6.1c-1.1-3.9-11.3-6.8-23.2-6.8c-12.9,0-23.4,3.3-23.4,7.6c0,0.2,0,0.2,0,0.4
        c0,1.5,1.5,3,1.5,3v11.1c-4.4-1.1-11.1-2.2-12.2-2.2c-0.4,0-0.9-0.2-1.3,0c0,0-1.7,0.7-2,0.9c-0.7,0.4-7.9,9.2-8.5,11.1
        c-0.2,0.2-0.2,0.4-0.2,0.9c2.2,9.2,11.1,43.3,12.9,47c0.7,1.3,8.3,2.2,11.1,2.6v3.7c-1.7,1.5-2.6,3-2.6,4.8v2.8
        c0,5.9,10.9,10.7,24.3,10.7s24.3-4.8,24.3-10.7v-2.8c0-1.5-0.7-3-2-4.2v-65.3H99.3z M55,200.8c-1.5-0.2-3.1-0.6-4.2-1.5
        c-1.8-1.5-3.3-4.1-3.1-6.6c0.2-2.6,0.2-5-0.4-7c-0.6-2-3-5.2-3.5-7c-0.7-3,0.4-7-0.4-10.5c-0.7-3.7-3-6.1-3-7.7c0-1.1,0.7-3.3,2-5
        c0.4-0.2,0.7-0.2,1.3-0.2c3.3,0.4,11.1,2.2,11.1,2.2H55L55,200.8L55,200.8z"/>
    
        <ellipse id="Path-2" dataid="RCS" opacity="0" onfocus="highlightStrand(evt)" onblur="dehighlightStrand(evt)" onmouseover="highlightStrand(evt)" onmouseout="dehighlightStrand(evt)" class="st0" cx="76.8" cy="121.5" rx="22.1" ry="8.1"/>
    
        <ellipse id="Path-3" dataid="RF-2" opacity="0" onfocus="highlightStrand(evt)" onblur="dehighlightStrand(evt)" onmouseover="highlightStrand(evt)" onmouseout="dehighlightStrand(evt)" class="st0" cx="76" cy="104.2" rx="23.6" ry="8.9"/>
    
        <path id="Path-4" dataid="FPS" opacity="0" onfocus="highlightStrand(evt)" onblur="dehighlightStrand(evt)" onmouseover="highlightStrand(evt)" onmouseout="dehighlightStrand(evt)" class="st0" d="
        M77.3,51.4v17.2c12.9,0.2,23.2,4.6,23.2,10.1s-10.3,10-23.2,10.2V97H78v5.2h-3.5V97h0.6v-8.1c-12.5-0.4-22.5-4.8-22.5-10.1
        c0-5.5,10-10,22.5-10.1V51.2c-3.9-0.7-5.7-2.4-7.6-2.8c-8.5-1.1-14.2-5.3-14.2-5.5v-5.3l-3-5.2l-0.2-0.2c-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.5
        c0-4.6,11.3-8.5,25.5-8.7v-6.5c-0.9-0.2-1.5-0.4-1.5-0.6v-1.3c-4.4-0.4-7.6-1.8-7.6-3.7c0-2,4.6-3.9,10.3-3.9s10.3,1.7,10.3,3.9
        c0,1.8-3.5,3.3-7.9,3.7v1.3c0,0.2-0.6,0.6-1.3,0.6V22c14,0.2,25.3,4.1,25.3,8.7c0,0.7-0.2,1.3-0.7,2L99,38v3.7c0,0.2,0,0.6-0.2,0.7
        c-0.6,1.8-3,3.5-6.6,4.8c-2.8,0.9-6.5,4.1-12.7,4.2C78.6,51.6,77.9,51.6,77.3,51.4z"/>
</g>

<script type="text/ecmascript">
     
     function highlightStrand(evt) {
        let el = evt.target;
        let current_id = el.getAttributeNS(null, "dataid");
        console.log(current_id);
        console.log('creating event  ');
        el.setAttributeNS(null,"opacity","0.5");
        /*ar event = document.createEvent("SVGEvemouseoversvgnts");
        event.initEvent("mouseover",true,true);
        document.dispatchEvent(event);*/
        
        const event = new CustomEvent('mouseoversvg', { detail: current_id,bubbles: true });
        el.dispatchEvent(event);
     }
     function dehighlightStrand(evt) {
        let el = evt.target;
        let current_id = el.getAttributeNS(null, "dataid");
        console.log(current_id);
        el.setAttributeNS(null,"opacity","0");
        var event = document.createEvent("SVGEvents");
        event.initEvent("mouseout",true,true);
        document.dispatchEvent(event);
     }

</script>
</svg>
```

Comment: Are you waiting for the object element's onload event to fire?

Comment: Hello. No I'm not, I can try that, but what's strange is that in the chrome dev console, even if I wait several minutes, all the object element aren't visible with document.getElementByID until I click on them in the console source.